# which msn java library is better?

Tags: java, msn

I want to use a java library instead of msn client to communicate with server. But which msn library is more easy to handle and more support documents? It is important such library can reconnect server if some reasons such as network is broken make msn offline.

Comment: Have a look at http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/java-jml, since it is th eonly one I can find. :-)

Comment: some open source such as jmsn,jml which is a java libary supporting to talk with msn server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the [JML](http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/java-jml), it has javadocs, links to project pages, source code browsers, example code, and more.